# [Heroku + GhostJs]_Incorrect server configuration between Heroku and Ghost

Tags: node.js, heroku, ghost, server-configuration

I'm a newbie and trying to create my own blog with heroku and ghost framework.
I have deployed my source into heroku with successful built. . But a error disappear when I connection to my blog domain (myblog.herokuapp.com).

I check log with command:

```
heroku logs --tail -n 200
```

And it said:

```
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
app[web.1]:     at Async._drainQueue (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
app[web.1]:     at Async._drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
app[web.1]:     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
app[web.1]:     at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
app[web.1]:     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
app[web.1]:     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: ERROR: invalid server configuration
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:  Error: invalid server configuration
app[web.1]:     at ConfigManager.validate (/app/core/server/config/index.js:458:31)
app[web.1]:     at /app/core/server/config/index.js:332:29
app[web.1]:     at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
app[web.1]:     at Async._drainQueue (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
app[web.1]:     at Async._drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
app[web.1]:     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
app[web.1]:     at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
app[web.1]:     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
app[web.1]: > node index
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: > ghost@0.11.10 start /app
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: ERROR: Your server values (socket, or host and port) in config.js are invalid.
app[web.1]:  Please provide them before restarting.
app[web.1]:  Error: Your server values (socket, or host and port) in config.js are invalid.
app[web.1]:     at ConfigManager.validate (/app/core/server/config/index.js:454:13)
app[web.1]:     at /app/core/server/config/index.js:332:29
app[web.1]:     at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
app[web.1]:     at Async._drainQueue (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
app[web.1]:     at Async._drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
app[web.1]:     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
app[web.1]:     at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
app[web.1]:     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
app[web.1]:     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:     at ConfigManager.validate (/app/core/server/config/index.js:458:31)
app[web.1]: ERROR: invalid server configuration
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:     at /app/core/server/config/index.js:332:29
app[web.1]:  Error: invalid server configuration
app[web.1]:     at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
app[web.1]:     at Async._drainQueue (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
app[web.1]:     at Async._drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
app[web.1]:     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
app[web.1]:     at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
app[web.1]:     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
app[web.1]:     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
app[web.1]:
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: > ghost@0.11.10 start /app
app[web.1]: > node index
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: ERROR: Your server values (socket, or host and port) in config.js are invalid.
app[web.1]:  Please provide them before restarting.
app[web.1]:  Error: Your server values (socket, or host and port) in config.js are invalid.
app[web.1]:     at ConfigManager.validate (/app/core/server/config/index.js:454:13)
app[web.1]:     at /app/core/server/config/index.js:332:29
app[web.1]:     at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
app[web.1]:     at Async._drainQueue (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
app[web.1]:     at Async._drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
app[web.1]:     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
app[web.1]:     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
app[web.1]:     at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: ERROR: invalid server configuration
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:  Error: invalid server configuration
app[web.1]:     at ConfigManager.validate (/app/core/server/config/index.js:458:31)
app[web.1]:     at /app/core/server/config/index.js:332:29
app[web.1]:     at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
app[web.1]:     at Async._drainQueue (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
app[web.1]:     at Async._drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
app[web.1]:     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
app[web.1]:     at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
app[web.1]:     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
app[web.1]:     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
app[web.1]:
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
app[web.1]: > node index
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: > ghost@0.11.10 start /app
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: ERROR: Your server values (socket, or host and port) in config.js are invalid.
app[web.1]:  Please provide them before restarting.
app[web.1]:  Error: Your server values (socket, or host and port) in config.js are invalid.
app[web.1]:     at ConfigManager.validate (/app/core/server/config/index.js:454:13)
app[web.1]:     at /app/core/server/config/index.js:332:29
app[web.1]:     at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
app[web.1]:     at Async._drainQueue (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
app[web.1]:     at Async._drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
app[web.1]:     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
app[web.1]:     at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
app[web.1]:     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
app[web.1]:     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: ERROR: invalid server configuration
app[web.1]:  Error: invalid server configuration
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:     at ConfigManager.validate (/app/core/server/config/index.js:458:31)
app[web.1]:     at /app/core/server/config/index.js:332:29
app[web.1]:     at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
app[web.1]:     at Async._drainQueue (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
app[web.1]:     at Async._drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
app[web.1]:     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
app[web.1]:     at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
app[web.1]:     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
app[web.1]:     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
app[web.1]:
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: > ghost@0.11.10 start /app
app[web.1]: > node index
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: ERROR: Your server values (socket, or host and port) in config.js are invalid.
app[web.1]:  Please provide them before restarting.
app[web.1]:  Error: Your server values (socket, or host and port) in config.js are invalid.
app[web.1]:     at ConfigManager.validate (/app/core/server/config/index.js:454:13)
app[web.1]:     at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
app[web.1]:     at Async._drainQueue (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
app[web.1]:     at Async._drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
app[web.1]:     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
app[web.1]:     at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
app[web.1]:     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
app[web.1]:     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:     at /app/core/server/config/index.js:332:29
app[web.1]: ERROR: invalid server configuration
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:  Error: invalid server configuration
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:     at ConfigManager.validate (/app/core/server/config/index.js:458:31)
app[web.1]:     at /app/core/server/config/index.js:332:29
app[web.1]:     at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
app[web.1]:     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
app[web.1]:     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
app[web.1]:     at Async._drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:     at Async._drainQueue (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
app[web.1]:     at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
app[web.1]:     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

I'm sure that the some problems in /root/config.js which i config as below 
process.env.SERVER_HOST = 0.0.0.0 and process.env.PORT = 3000

```
server: {
        host: process.env.SERVER_HOST,
        port: process.env.PORT
    }
```

Does anyone has any idea to correct this problem?

Comment: I see you're using Ghost 0.11. In that case, this guide worked for me: http://www.autodidacts.io/host-a-ghost-blog-on-heroku/

Comment: Hi,
I've tried that guide before but It doesn't work. This is content of my "Procfile.txt". Does Procfile has extension ".txt"?

>web: NODE_ENV=production node index.js

And I config environment variable as below:
=== minhtrietblog Config Vars
DATABASE_URL:      DB_URL
PORT:              3000
POSTGRES_DATABASE: DB_NAME
POSTGRES_HOST:     Host
POSTGRES_PASSWORD: Pass
POSTGRES_USER:     User
NODE_ENV:          production
PRODUCTION_URL:    https://URL.herokuapp.com/
SERVER_HOST:       0.0.0.0

Comment: In there guide, they said as below. But what is value of "process.env.PORT"? is it 3000 or 2368?

server: {  
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  port: process.env.PORT
}

Comment: The guide is correct for versions of Ghost <= 0.11.x. `Procfile` doesn't have any extension. Heroku assigns your app a random port, so you **must** not set the `PORT` env var. Heroku does it for you. Also I'm assuming you're giving the `POSTGRES_` vars the right values from your DB add-on resource.

Answer (score 0):

I find out this [url](https://github.com/cobyism/ghost-on-heroku) so I create another blog within 2 minutes